# S3.getObjectTagging is not a function

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I was trying to use getObjectTagging api to get tags of an object from S3 bucket. Here are the configurations of my code.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

module.exports.getObjectTagging = function(credentials, bucketParam) {

    AWS.config.update(credentials);
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {
        Bucket: "bucket-name",
        Key: "key"
    };
    s3.getObjectTagging(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
       else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   });
}
```

Reference : https://ibm.github.io/ibm-cos-sdk-js/AWS/S3.html#getObjectTagging-property

But this method is giving this error : s3.getObjectTagging is not a function and I'm not able to figure out what might be causing this.

Comment: Which version of the sdk are you using?  The latest version has a very different API.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/getobjecttaggingcommand.html